# Why is the angle units of phasor form in degrees and not in radians?

Tags: power-supply, power

The question below:

[image]

The correct answer is "B."

Why isn't also "A" a correct answer?

I tried the numbers in my Classwiz calculator and both gave the same rectangular answer.

Here the angle unit used is degree:

[image]

Here the angle unit is radian:

[image]

Of course if I put the angle as π/3 while using degrees as a reference unit it would give a wrong answer (as shown below) just like putting 60 and using radians to be the reference angle unit.

[image]

why isn't option A a correct answer although in option A it says rad?

[image]

Comment: Who says that only one answer is correct?

Comment: I would say all four options are correct !   So it must be due to convention used in your book , because mathematically this can be expressed in all 4possible phasors given in option